# How to get asterisk '*' in zsh to have same behaviour as bash?

Tags: zsh, wildcards, oh-my-zsh

I have recently switched from bash to zsh and now when I type

```
ls *
```

It does not simply list all files in this directory, but shows a tree of two levels.

Also

```
rm -rf somepath/*
```

fails with the output `zsh: no matches found:`

This used to work just fine with bash. Can anyone help me to get this behaviour back?

I do have oh-my-zsh installed.

Comment: Bash would expand the `*` wildcard to directories (thus `ls` would show those directories' contents); did you change bash's behavior somehow?

Comment: I got a bit confused about this. It turns out this was all just a matter of using sudo and globbing not working with sudo.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`ls *` would have the same effect in bash. No matter what the shell is, what happens is that the shell first expands the wildcards, and then passes the result of the expansion to the command. For example, suppose the current directory contains four entries: two subdirectories `dir1` and `dir2`, and two regular files `file1` and `file2`. Then the shell expands `ls *` to `ls dir1 dir2 file1 file2`. The `ls` command first lists the names of the arguments that are existing non-directories, then lists the contents of each directory in turn.

```
$ ls
dir1  dir2  file1  file2
$ ls -F
dir1/  dir2/  file1  file2
$ ls *
file1  file2

dir1:
…

dir2:
…
```

If `ls` behaved differently in bash, either you've [changed the bash configuration](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/589530) to turn off wildcard expansions, which would turn it off everywhere, or you've changed the meaning of the `ls` command to suppress the listing of directories, probably with an alias. Specifically, having

```
alias ls='ls -d'
```

in your `~/.bashrc` would have exactly the effect you describe. If that's what you did, you can copy this line to `~/.zshrc` and you'll have the same effect.

---

The fact that `rm -rf somepath/*` has a different effect in bash and zsh when `somepath` is an empty directory is a completely different matter.

In bash, if `somepath/*` doesn't match any files, then bash leaves the wildcard pattern in the command, so `rm` sees the arguments `-rf` and `somepath/*`. `rm` tries to delete the file called `*` in the directory `somepath`, and since there's no such file, this attempt fails. Since you passed the option `-f` to `rm`, it doesn't complain about a missing file.

In zsh, by default, if a wildcard doesn't match any files, zsh treats this as an error. You can change the way zsh behaves by turning off the option [`nomatch`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Options.html#index-NOMATCH):

```
setopt no_nomatch
```

I don't recommend this because having the shell tell you when a wildcard doesn't match is usually the preferable behavior on the command line. There's a much better way to tell zsh that in this case, an empty list is ok:

```
rm -rf somepath/*(N)
```

`N` is a [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) that says to expand to an empty list if the wildcard doesn't match any file.

Comment: Thank you! I see that I am mistaken regarding the use of `ls *`. Regarding the rm, I did find the cause. It was due to using sudo. Could it be that the globbing does not work with sudo?

Comment: @morja Globbing works with sudo, but it takes place **before** sudo. So globbing won't work in a directory that you don't have permission to read. This is the same in bash and in zsh.

Comment: Yes, I understand now. Thanks a lot!

Comment: If I want to e.g. copy files from one of my machines using scp, for example, with bash I can say
`scp mach:path/to/* .`
to copy all files from the remote machine. With zsh without the no_nomatch option, this fails with an error, forcing me to escape the wildcards, since zsh cannot tell when it should pass wildcards through rather than trying to expand them.

Answer (score 1):

You have configured the Bourne Again shell with a non-default option, `nullglob`.  This makes `ls *` in an empty directory turn into plain `ls`, and `rm -rf somepath/*` where that subdirectory is empty turn into `rm -rf`.

To achieve the same effect with the Z shell, you need a similar non-default option, by the same name:

```
setopt nullglob
```

The Z shell has another option that turns on slightly different behaviour:

```
setopt cshnullglob
```

With this option, `ls *` and `rm -rf somepath/*` are still flagged as matching errors, but `rm -rf empty/* hasfiles/*` is not and ignores the `empty/*`, not passing it to `rm`.
It allows *some* patterns to expand to nothing, as long as *at least one* does not.

Comment: Presumably `ls` in an empty directory wouldn’t show “a tree of two levels”...

Comment: If the directory was empty, zsh should presumably also croak for the glob in `ls`, like it does for the one in `rm`